# declaring variable with same name causes problems in socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

It took me a while to figure out what the problem was, but I'm wondering why it's acting like that.

Using this code, the variables player, players and socket will be undefined, causing errors.

```
var player = Player(socket.id, socket);

socket.on('joinHost', function(data) {
    var gameID = data;
    player.gameID=gameID;
    var game = GAME_LIST[gameID];
    game.players[socket.id]=player;
    var players = game.players;
    for (var p in players){
        var player = players[p];
        var socket = player.socket;
        socket.emit('playerJoined');
    }
});
```

Avoiding the declarations of variables with same names makes it all work correctly.

```
var player = Player(socket.id, socket);

socket.on('joinHost', function(data) {
    var gameID = data;
    player.gameID=gameID;
    var game = GAME_LIST[gameID];
    game.players[socket.id]=player;
    var tempPlayers = game.players;
    for (var p in tempPlayers){
        var tempPlayer = tempPlayers[p];
        var tempSocket = tempPlayer.socket;
        tempSocket.emit('playerJoined');
    }
});
```

The interesting part is, when I ran the first code, it says the player in the line `player.gameID=gameID` is undefined, while if I removed the code which is after `player.gameID=gameID`, the player was defined. Basically, the code after `player.gameID=gameID` caused the player to be undefined.

So, why is this happening?

Comment: Umm, is Player a constructor? If so, try `var player = new Player(socket.id, socket);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `var player = players[p];` it is declared for the whole function scope (the for loop doesn't has a scope of it's own).

The names in the current scope are evaluated all in the beginning, before executing the function body.

So when `function(data)` is called, the name `player` is overridden in that scope even before `var gameID = data;` is executed.

A minimal example:

```
> var x = 'foo';
> f = function() { console.log(x); var x = 'bar'; }
> f()
undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript moves variables's declaration to the top of the scope they were defined and gives them an *undefined* initial value but keeps assignment in place. This is called **hoisting**

Your code is equivalent to :

```js
var player = Player(socket.id, socket);

socket.on('joinHost', function(data) {
    var gameID;   // undefined
    var game;     // undefined
    var players;  // undefined
    var player;   // undefined
    var socket;   // undefined
    
    gameID = data;
    player.gameID=gameID; // can't set property 'gameID' of undefined
    game = GAME_LIST[gameID];
    game.players[socket.id]=player;  // is undefined since 'player' is undefined at this stage
    players = game.players;  // undefined
    for (var p in players){
        player = players[p];
        socket = player.socket;
        socket.emit('playerJoined');
    }
});
```